# Assign a value in elm

Tags: elm

This is a really noob question, i'm sorry but my search on the internet can't find the answer. I have the following code:

```
-- MODEL

type alias Model = Int

model : Model
model =
  0


-- UPDATE

type Msg = Increment | Decrement | Reset

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Increment ->
      model + 1

    Decrement ->
      model - 1
    Reset ->
      model = 0
```

I am trying to implement the reset that sets the model value to 0. But i'm getting a compilation error:

> The = operator is reserved for defining variables. Maybe you want == instead? Or
>   maybe you are defining a variable, but there is whitespace before it?

Please help!

Comment: Did you mean to write just `0` instead of `model = 0`?

Comment: Yes I did, thank you! I didn't realise i was already in an equals for the model value.

Comment: Haha I am at the exact same point in the tutorial!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You only need to write the model's new value there. In this case, that'll be just `0`:

```
Reset ->
  0
```